# Rider 2017.3 highlighting HTML issue

Tags: c#, html, jetbrains-ide, rider

I got a problem that give me headache...

So I work on a project with virtuals includes (IIS style) I can not change that, it's historical and not my concern.

Visual studio is OK with that, and Rider too, but for sometimes, Rider makes all the HTML code highlight wrong like this :

[image: Html looks ok, and then after the include, it's all wrong]

The only thing I can do about it : <kbd>Cmd + A</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd + X</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd + V</kbd>... and highlighting is OK again... but it's time consuming..

Anyone had this issue?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, did you try reporting this to Jetbrains? Sounds like a bug to me. And don't forget that Rider is a new product so some hiccups are expected.

Comment: Thanks for that, i was not sure if it was a miss-configuration or a bug...

Comment: This may be related to wrong file type (Settings -> Editor -> File Types) set for your extension. But yes, you probably should file an issue in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com